# Does Android Development obviate 32-bit Linux

Tags: 64-bit, android, 32-bit, development, emulation

Recently I encountered the following error while trying to emulate Android using Cordova:

```
    ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED when attemping to run the Android emulator

....
       please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

I was, however, able to run the emulator using:

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

So, does this mean that my 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 will be obsolete for developing Android apps in the future and I need to invest in a machine running 64-bit OS?

Comment: Heh. If you wanted to run a pure 32-bit desktop, that'd take some investing. Are there any consumer desktop 32-bit CPUs these days? I'd expect your system, if released any time in the past 5-6 years and has an Intel or AMD CPU, is also 64-bit.

Comment: Yes, itś quite clear. But unless your machine is real old, it should be able to run a 64bits unless it's ancient.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of certain ARM environments, purely 32-bit Desktops are obsolete.

The standard CPU in computers of the last five or six years is primarily 64-bit architecture.  As such, it is relatively safe to assume that your processor isn't restricted to a 32-bit environment.  With the various improvements in processing power between 32bit and 64bit,
it makes sense the standard would be 64bit nowadays.

---

If Android says they will drop 32-but development environment support in the future that's their call, though.  True you can 'force' it to run 32-bit but soon enough that will probably cease to be the case.

With the standard being 64bit you should likely consider getting a 64bit OS.  You may not have to replace the entire system to achieve this unless your processor is only 32bits (in which case that system is obsoleted by today's standard consumer level PCs off the shelf which have 64bit CPUs and you should start considering upgrading if you do development)

Comment: Thanks for your response and yes my system can be upgraded to 64bit. Probably I should haved asked a bit differently. Currently I'm running 32bit Ubuntu 14.04. As it is with most linux distros, I have spent quite a deal of effort and time customizing, fine tuning and getting it to serve most of my needs. Now, I either have to get a completely new system just for Android development or make a clean install on my old pc. Either way I have to spend extra resources !